# Regex not working, following wrong path in argument

Tags: regex, awk

I have a regex argument. that checks the content of a variable in this case the content is a time, in the format of HH:MM:SS but when running the line of code the system follows the path to show it has failed and doesn't meet the criteria.
`!($11~/^(?:[01]?\d|2[0-3]):[0-5]\d:[0-5]\d|^$/) {print "11th field invalid";}`
that's the aforementioned code and here is the contents of the variable "11:40:59".

now I want the code to carry on through the program if a time Is contained inside the variable . however if there is for example an alphabetic character inside the variable I want the program to print "11th field invalid" and exit the program.

also I check the regex argument in tester along with the variable and it matched

Comment: There are a variety of dialects in the regex world and you'll need to modify yours to conform to awk's.  Look here to see what's allowed: https://www.math.utah.edu/docs/info/gawk_5.html  (assuming you have gnu awk, otherwise find the relevant doc)

Comment: I did use this documentation to see if I broke any awk rules but from what I could see I meet all the rules and they carry the same meaning

Comment: I may certainly be mistaken but, for example, I don't think `\d` is supported for matching a digit. Also, you start a sequence with `?:` which I guess is supposed to denote a "non-capturing group"?  I'm pretty sure awk has no support for that.

Comment: [edit] your question to include concise, testable sample input and expected output so we can help you. When you say `the variable` do you mean `the 11th field`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using an ERE as supported by awk this PCRE (if I understand it correctly):

```
!($11~/^(?:[01]?\d|2[0-3]):[0-5]\d:[0-5]\d|^$/)
```

would be:

```
!($11~/^([01]?[0-9]|2[0-3]):[0-5][0-9]:[0-5][0-9]|^$/)
```

but you could write the expression instead as:

```
!($11~/^([01]?[0-9]|2[0-3])(:[0-5][0-9]){2}|^$/)
```

and it's still missing the terminating `$` in the non-null part so it should actually be:

```
!($11~/^(([01]?[0-9]|2[0-3])(:[0-5][0-9]){2})?$/)
```

or:

```
$11 !~ /^(([01]?[0-9]|2[0-3])(:[0-5][0-9]){2})?$/
```

Answer (score 1):

Awk doesn't support [PCRE](https://www.pcre.org/). As mentioned in the comment, the `\d` and `?:` is not supported.

If you use GNU awk, an alternative to test if the time is correct is to use `mktime` function.

```
split($11, a, ":")  
if(mktime("2019 1 1 " a[1] " " a[2] " " a[3]) == -1){ 
   print "11th field invalid"
}
```

The first line fills the array a with the hour, minute, second fields.
The function `mktime` returns `-1` if the date creation fails.

Comment: thank you are correct along with jas I was confusing the meanings of '?'. with this code how would I add a option to leave the variable blank. like you would with regex using ^

Comment: You can test the result of `split`. It returns the number of fields in the array.   Something like: `if(split(...)){if(mktime(...){print ...}}`. If the 11th variable is empty, `split` will return 0 and the if statement will not be executed.